# ss5 and netstat

Tags: fedora, socks

I am using ss5 on fedora 11, trying to start in on a custom port, but it seems to end up listen on 1080.  please see netstat below, and why is the local address 255.255.255.255?

ss5 -b 0.0.0.0/123

```
[root@fedora ~]# netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 255.255.255.255:1080        0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 174.143.169.62:22           12.36.36.80:32614           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    248 174.143.169.62:22           12.36.36.80:32987           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6890   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7136   @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  5      [ ]         DGRAM                    13455  /dev/log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    18875  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    13621  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    13560  
[root@fedora ~]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to specify ss5 -b 0.0.0.0:123. So you'll use a : instead of a /

Also if you're using port 123 you need to run the command as root

The slash you're specifying may also be part of your problem with how it shows up in netstat-typically with a slash you're specifying a netblock.

Comment: yes you are right on both, I should've issued:
ss5 -u root -b 0.0.0.0:123